# Delay on while loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, slider, while-loop

I've tried to make an automated slider, although it seems my code isn't working - it either crashes the browser or it just executes very fast.

what I've been playing around with is the `setTimeout`, but it doesn't seem to work in a while-loop.

```
var playSlider = true;

if(playSlider) {
    var i = $('#sliderwrapper ul li:visible').attr('data-number');
    var lengthLi = $('#sliderwrapper ul li').size();
    while(i<=lengthLi) {
        var x = i + 1;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#sliderwrapper ul li[data-number=' + i + ']').fadeOut(450);
            $('#sliderwrapper ul li[data-number=' + x + ']').fadeIn(600);
        }, 3000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li data-number="1" data-description="Buy now!"><img src="images/slider1.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="2" data-description="Buy later!"><img src="images/slider2.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="3"><img src="images/slider3.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="4"><img src="images/slider4.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="5"><img src="images/slider5.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="6"><img src="images/slider2.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="7"><img src="images/slider3.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="8"><img src="images/slider5.png" border="0"></li>
    <li data-number="9"><img src="images/slider1.png" border="0"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't have the id `sliderwrapper` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/egopos/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
var $li = $('#sliderwrapper ul li');
var N = $li.length;
var C = 0 ;
var intv ;

$li.hide().eq(C).show();

function loop(){
  intv = setInterval(function(){
    $li.eq( ++C % N ).fadeTo(500,1).siblings().fadeTo(500,0);
  },3000);
}
loop(); 

$('#sliderwrapper').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function( e ){      
    var mEnt = e.type=='mouseenter' ? clearInterval( intv ) : loop() ;      
});
```

Comment: Ah, okay. But I were to need it to be paused or resumed, do i just need to put down a if-statement on the function call?

Comment: Oh im sorry, i thought you would understand since i had a 

var playSlider = true;

Comment: @user2021893 no problem ! :) it was not obvious from the question and the issue explanation. Look at my edited comment above

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm gonna try and implement it now!

Comment: @user2021893 :) you're welcome! Happy coding, if you encounter any issue feel free to leave a comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .delay("3000") to put pauses between JQuery commands

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of things that I changed...

```
var playSlider = true;
if(playSlider) {
    var i = $('#sliderwrapper ul li:visible').attr('data-number');
    var lengthLi = $('#sliderwrapper ul li').length();
    while(i <= lengthLi) {
        var x = i + 1;
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#sliderwrapper ul li[data-number=' + i + ']').fadeOut(450);
            $('#sliderwrapper ul li[data-number=' + x + ']').fadeIn(600);
        }, 3000 * i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I changed `.size()` to `.length()` to count the li elements (size is deprecated), and I changed the timeout to `3000 * i`, otherwise they'd all fade out and in after 3 seconds, at the same time.

Comment: This should do the trick.
To elaborate on the answer: OP, your code didn't appear to work because `setTimeout` is asynchronous. The `while` loop will not wait for the `setTimeout` function to run, it will instead set all the timeouts directly, then 3 seconds later, all of them will trigger at about the same time.

Comment: Thanks Cerbrus - I probably should have mentioned that setTimeout is non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

Then a bit recursion will help you:

```
function rec(){
    //your code and so on
    setTimeout(function(){
        rec();
    },3000);
}
```

Comment: This made the browser crash :/